# Flutter draw container with a curve in the center

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I'd like to draw the black container  shape with flutter.

[image]

Comment: You can use `ClipPath`. Are you just referring to the top gap?

Comment: yes just the top curve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, the first time I thought it was a cut, I was thinking in a `ClipPath` widget, but now I see you have a Circle widget at the top of your black `Container`.

This is an example:

```dart
class FunnyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const FunnyContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _childContainer() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            width: 4,
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 40),
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Expanded(child: _childContainer()),
                  Expanded(child: _childContainer()),
                  Expanded(child: _childContainer()),
                ],
              ),
              const Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: -50,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  radius: 40,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**UPDATE** (Using your updated design)

Now the you updated your post, this could be done using Clippers, the problem is that clip needs Shadow, so I took this code : https://gist.github.com/coman3/e631fd55cd9cdf9bd4efe8ecfdbb85a7

And I used on this example:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
          child: ClipShadowPath(
            clipper: _MyClipper(100),
            shadow: const Shadow(
              blurRadius: 15,
              color: Colors.grey,
              offset: Offset(0, 10),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: const [
                    Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double space;

  _MyClipper(this.space);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final halfWidth = size.width / 2;
    final halfSpace = space / 2;
    final curve = space / 6;
    final height = halfSpace / 1.4;
    path.lineTo(halfWidth - halfSpace, 0);
    path.cubicTo(halfWidth - halfSpace, 0, halfWidth - halfSpace + curve,
        height, halfWidth, height);

    path.cubicTo(halfWidth, height, halfWidth + halfSpace - curve, height,
        halfWidth + halfSpace, 0);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

RESULT

[image]

You just need to update the Path in order to get the rounded corners of the `Container`.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, i made a mistake, actually the container is white not black

Comment: Well, you can customize the code, or do you require any other major change?

Comment: yes, the container is white and the half circle is transparent, so your solution didn't work because they have same color

Comment: I don't understand, I'm just following the image you posted, you can change the colors of the containers.

Comment: I have updated the design, please take a look again

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Position a transparent png on top of your container.

```
    child: Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.black,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0, 3),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/half-circle.png', fit: BoxFit.contain, alignment: new Alignment(-1.0, -1.0)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
      ),
    ),
```

Image:

[image]

[Live example](https://flutlab.io/ide/80debdec-bfe3-47ed-af17-599f611e4ee3)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Stack` which may write draw circle on top of the container like this:

```dart
class BlackContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlackContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: child,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.black,
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 10,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: -25,
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BlackContainer(
          child: Text(
            'Content here',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyText2!
                .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```